# Python Common Word List with Frequency Greater than 1

Tags: python, list

Suppose I've a list here:

```
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'cat', 'wolf', 'cat', 'sheep', 'sheep']
```

I want to fetch only those words from which are having common frequency greater than 1.

Resultant list should be:

```
['cat', 'wolf', 'sheep']
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `'wolf'` doesn't have a frequency greater than 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of repetitions, then use a list comprehension to keep only those with a count greater than 1.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ['cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'cat', 'wolf', 'cat', 'sheep', 'sheep']
>>> c = Counter(words)
>>> [k for k, v in c.items() if v > 1]
['cat', 'wolf', 'sheep']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'cat', 'wolf', 'cat']

items_map = {}
for item in list:
    if item not in items_map.keys():
        items_map[item] = 1
    else:
        items_map[item] += 1

result = []

for key in items_map.keys():
    if items_map[key] > 1:
        result.append(key)

print(result)
```